# Flash Pro cc why is the stage width and height on my phone, set as the one inside Flash pro?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

I am having problem setting the stage height and width for the app i am developing.

I need to set the height and width as for the screen of the device it is on. So i do stage.fullScreenHeight and stage.fullScreenWidth.

But i just realized that the fullScreenHeight and width it is setting is the size for the stage inside flash pro cc under properties(the stage size).

And i am not able to make the stage width and height according to the phone's. Even if i do Capabilities.screenResolutionX; or stage.stageHeight. All of them set to either the size of the image, or the stage inside flash pro, but none is according to the device.

Edit:

```
E.g. var button = Button = new Button(); 
button.width = stage.stageWidth;
button.height = Button.width/stage.stageWidth * Button.height;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE

or unchecking "full screen" checkbox in your Air settings

Comment: Is it possible if i set (for example a button) to no scale? E.g. button.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.No_SCALE?

Comment: As far as i know you cannot. But maybe .scaleX and .scaleY properties will help you. E.g. button.scaleX = 1.5